# Can not create an "evil twin access point" with the same SSID as the original

Tags: penetration-test, evil-twin, rogue-ap

I am practising pen-testing for a while now and I have a kali Linux 2017.2 physical machine. I tried to create an evil twin access point using tools like fluxion, wifiphisher and  wifi-pumpkin. Note that I used an Alpha Card AR9271.

When the access point is created does not have the same name as the target network.  For example if the network's name is "dog", after the creation the available network name is "dog 2" instead of "dog". Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you seeing the name SSID2 instead of SSID, this could be just the machine that you are using to find the APs rather than the AP being started with that name. Do you see the same AP name on multiple devices?

Comment: I checked that and another 2 machines showed the AP with the SSID2.